# Vue stack components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm building server UI and I'm struggling with components. Maybe someone knows how to stack all components and control all UI with functions?
example

- App.vue

  - chat.vue
  - hud.vue
  - player.vue

I need to display all `.vue` in `app.vue`

**App.vue**

```
import chat from './components/chat.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    chat
  }
}
```

**chat.vue**

```
export default {
    methods: {
        test: function() {
            console.log("test");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call the function **test** in the DevTools console, when I run the webiste?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the [Vue Dev Tools browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en)? That will let you inspect all components on a page and tweak their data/props.

I don't think it will let you call their methods, but if you need to call one of those methods in the console you might try (temporarily, for testing purposes) making a component instance available on the window inside a `mounted` lifecycle function.

EDIT: Is that your entire App.vue, by the way? I'm thinking maybe I misunderstood your question and you think that...

```
  components: {
    chat
  }
```

...means that it should render the component on the page. It only makes it available for the parent component to use. You have to place it inside a `<template>` to actually render it.